# SSRS Report is taking to long to load while sql is fast

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a SSRS report which has multiple report parameters and this report is a subreport included within the main report.

This subreport is taking hell amount of time (around 40 min) to fetch the result. while the SQL query is taking only 10 seconds.

I tried to use OPTION (Optimize For Unknown) Considering parameter sniffing, but no luck. I already invested half a day in trying various options.

Comment: id trace the DB to see what is really happening when running the report. it could be running the subreport for each record in the main resultset

Comment: Did you check it's really execution and not rendering to take a time? Did you compare both execution plans?

Comment: Hey Jeremy thaks for the reply .. i saw in the ExecutionLog3 the report is taking too much time during timedataretrieval. i read somewhere to remove all the unneccesory datset and did so as well but no luck.

Comment: @sepupic what do you mean by both the execution plans? how to do so could you please suggest?

Comment: When you run your report from reporting and from SSMS, server creates execution plans that obviously are different (you answered previously that it's not rendering but dataretrieval that takes time), so you should get both plans to compare them. You can search for them in the plan cache using sys.dm_exec_query_stats by query text (cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text) , query stats gives you plan handle and you get the plan when cross applying sys.dm_exec_query_plan. Or just use a Profiler when launching your report